# Add promises to a loop for my Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, kendo-grid, promise

I've got a Kendo grid with a checkbox in the first column of each row. After the user selects their checkboxes/rows and hits Submit, I need to do a post for each selected row and then do a callback when all have completed. Here's what I've currently got, which obviously doesn't work:

```
var myGrid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

myGrid.tbody.find(">tr").each(function () {
    var dataItem = myGrid.dataItem(this);

    //if the current row is selected, then post it for processing
    if (this.cells[0].firstChild.checked) {
        $.post("/Controller/Action/" + dataItem.itemId, function (returnJson) {
            if (returnJson.succeeded) {
                //append success msg to message div
            }
            else {
                //append error msg to message div
            }
        });
    }
}).promise().done(function () {
    //notify the user once all have completed
});
```

I would prefer to implement the promises via jQuery since we use jQuery quite a bit in our project, but I'm open to other solutions, as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lucky that `$.post` already returns a jqXHR object which is a promise.

We'll push all the promises to an array and then tell jQuery to explicitly wait for them:

```
var promises = [];
myGrid.tbody.find(">tr").each(function () {
    var dataItem = myGrid.dataItem(this);

    //if the current row is selected, then post it for processing
    if (this.cells[0].firstChild.checked) {
        var p = $.post("/Controller/Action/" + dataItem.itemId, function (returnJson) {
            if (returnJson.succeeded) {
                //append success msg to message div
            }
            else {
                //append error msg to message div
            }
        });
        promises.push(p); // add the $.post call
    }
})

// then to notify, $.when waits for several promises
$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(results){
      // all ready!
});
```